# Count multiple rows based on one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think I'm just not getting search results as this should be answered somewhere here since I'm having trouble just typing a title.

My table looks like this:

```
Name        Element  City  
Design Inc  51024    New York  
Plant Corp  51024    Chicago  
Energy Ltd  9665     Boston
```

If I write

```
Select Name, Element, City  
From Table  
Where City = 'New York'
```

Based on the Element, here it's the same value, I want the output to be a

count of

```
For New York  
Name = 2  
Element = 1
```

The same output would be for Chicago. I'm having trouble with where clause because obviously if I put = to a city, all I get is one row.

Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You need `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) AS Name_count, COUNT(DISTINCT Element) AS Element_count
FROM Table t
WHERE City = 'New York'
GROUP BY Element;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` to get all rows where the `element` is the same of any row where the city is New York. Then use `count()` to get your counts.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t1.name),
       count(DISTINCT t1.element)
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM elbat t2
                            WHERE t2.element = t1.element
                                  AND t2.city = 'New York');
```